# Erlang: specifying a working directory for mnesia?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

How do I specify a working directory for `mnesia` without resorting to passing the "dir" parameter on the command-line?

In other words, can I specify a "working directory" for mnesia just before calling `mnesia:start()' ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`application:set_env(mnesia, dir, Dir).`

Comment: There is an application_controller process started in Erlang VM. 
`application_controller:set_env` is the "API" to this process. `application:set_env` is a more abstract call, that just deals with applications. No wonder though that currently it only calls into that API.

Comment: To answer the question :), I believe that the existence of application_controller server and module should be regarded as "implementation detail", and thus the proper way is to use the application module.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the method call mentioned in other responses here you can also specify this in a system configuration file or .app file specified with the -config parameter. See http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#id2270704 for more information. This allows you keep the configuration seperate from the code and avoid a lot of command line flags.

Comment: I have a similar situation ... and I don't want to set mnesia dir from inside the code ... Can you please elaborate how .app file of an application should be used to set env variable for other application. I understand how this can be done using .config file though. e.g. My application file is test.app and it had mnesia listed in "applications" section, so mnesia is started automatically when I start "test". How can I pass "dir" value to mnesia using test.app?

Comment: the relevant documentation for that is here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/app.html specifically the env tuple in the application file spec. anything you can set with set_env() can also be set there or on the commandline.